# Set name for downloading excel file

Tags: javascript

I use below code to download my table as a Excel file. Is there are any way to set a name to downloading file. Because currently it gives a random characters. I tried several methods. Non of them worked for me.

```
<script>
var tableToExcel = (function() {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table >{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
    return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'White Card ${ patientName }', table: table.innerHTML}

    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
    }
})()
</script>
```

Comment: @jcubic Thank you. I'll try that